# Unable to format links with alternate text

Tags: google-hangouts

The snazzy new [Google Hangouts Chat](https://chat.google.com) seems to support formatting [links with alternate text like this one](/#) using this syntax

---

[image]

*Source: [https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic_)*

---

However, their web UI does not give the `<URL|text>` syntax any special treatment:

[image: 2]

Is the syntax to format links in the UI is different than the API, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked is only relevant to calls made via API or webhooks. Only [limited message formatting](https://support.google.com/hangoutschat/answer/7649118?hl=en) is offered via the Web UI and it does not appear that URL formatting is included.

Comment: Thanks @Justin Cervero. The link to Web UI message formatting is exactly what I was looking for.